# What versions of Android are unsupported with Twitter4J?

Tags: android, twitter4j

Does the Twitter4J library for Android work for all Android versions?  I cannot find anything regarding this issue on twitter4j's website, or anywhere else.
[twitter4j.org](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website indicates any version of Android works.  You need 1.4.2 or greater, which Android provides.

Twitter4J is featuring:
✔ 100% Pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 1.4.2 or later
✔ Android platform and Google APP Engine ready

**EDIT**  [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/118d5e9f1e74912a/05b146331da3d28a?lnk=gst&q=android#05b146331da3d28a) in the discussion group showed some issues running with Dalvik, which have been fixed.  You'll probably need to run some integration tests.

Comment: ahh thanks, i wasn't sure i could rely on the `1.4.2 or greater` line there, as it didn't mention `Android`

Answer (score 1):

Twitter4J should work on any version of Android SDK.
But make sure that you use the latest version of Twitter4J as there are several Android specific issues reported against older versions.
http://twitter4j.org/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=android